# Why do html form inputs automatically get disabled?

Tags: html, forms, input, disabled-input, rightjs

I am using the RightJS javascript framework. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with this behavior or not. I have a form on my page and I use `$('some_form').send();` to send the form to the server via a Post. The form submission works fine and request goes through to the server without error but after all the inputs in the form become disabled. Does anyone know what might be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the preventDefault() function

```
$('form').send({
  spinner:    $('spinner'),
  onComplete: preventDefault()
});
```

Its a jQuery feature